# Is it possible to check if a HTML file consists of a external js loaded to it?

Tags: jquery

With this below code i can check if a page consists of a particular css file or not ,

```
var cssUrl = 'css/homedelivery_styles.css';

if($('link[rel*=style][href="'+cssUrl+'"]').length==0)
{
$("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+cssUrl+'"/>');
}
```

Similarly is it possible to check if a file consists of any particular external file or not ??

I am aware of typeOf solutuion , but don't want to use it as i need to modify the js files for this .

Comment: do you use development tools like FireBug or Chromes built-in dev tool? Have you tried looking under the net diagnostics tab to listen for all requests being made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all the script tags on your page, iterate through them, and see if there are http(s) tags in the url or two forward slashes.

```
function hasExternalJavascript() {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        if (scripts[i].hasAttribute('src') && scripts[i].getAttribute('src').match(/http|\/\//)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you want to look for an exact file, you can modify the check to see if it matches the url you specified like so:

```
function hasExternalJavascript(url) {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        if (scripts[i].hasAttribute('src') && scripts[i].getAttribute('src') === url) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```